# How to define a custom compare function to sort a matrix according as one dimensional array sort

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, matrix, cross-platform

I'm trying to sort two dimensional array (matrix) while one dimensional array as is  sorted relevant to row order.

How can I define a suitable compare function?

(or. should I have to code my own retro style bubble sort function)

```
double matrix[4][3];
double id[4];
fillAllArrays();//declared somewhere
std::sort(std::begin(matrix),std::end(matrix),compare);
//how can I define compare function ?
```

the following demonstration displays the input two arrays (BEFORE) and what I want to them sorted like in section (AFTER) as I sort id array values, relevant rows of matrix should be identically reorder.

(Thanks in advance for any response and ideas)

BEFORE

```
double matrix[4][3]
0.45 0.67 0.41
0.94 0.34 0.34
0.12 0.50 0.42
0.34 0.52 0.74

double id[4]
35
67
12
47
```

---

AFTER

```
double matrix[4][3]
0.12 0.50 0.42
0.45 0.67 0.41
0.34 0.52 0.74
0.94 0.34 0.34

double id[4]
12
35
47
67
```

Comment: It is not clear how you are going to sort arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving the rows of the matrix around during sorting is something you should avoid. Instead I would sort a vector of

```
struct IdAndIndex{ 
    double id;
    int index;
};
```

that contains your `id` and the original index in the array. Once you sorted that `std::vector<IdAndIndex>` you can rearrange the matrix rows accordingly.

Or if you really want to sort the matrix directly (maybe it is small) you could instead sort a vector of

```
struct IdAndRow {
    double id;
    double[3] row;
    bool operator<(const IdAndRow& other) { return id < other.id; }
};
```

Comment: I catch a function in matlab namely sortrows

Comment: @N.Ramos I dont understand what you mean.

Comment: thanks for answer. I mean there is a function called "sortrows" in MATLAB. which is eactly what I want.